# The method executeQuery(String[]) from the type DBUtil refers to the missing type UncategorizedSQLException

Tags: java, jdbc, compiler-errors

i face this error and my code is

```
try {

        String[] aray = new String[]{userOpLogObj.getLogQuery(), insertQry};

        String result = DBUtil.executeQuery(aray);
        if (result.equals("1")) {
            return "1";
        } else {
            return "-1";
        }
    } catch (DBException e) {

        return "-1,DBEX," + e.getError();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        return "-1" + ex;
    }

}
```

i try everything own my own but nothing happened

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace and share the content of `DBUtil.executeQuery`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.